# Sybase ASE 15.7 sort ordering

Tags: order-by, collation, sybase, sorting, sybase-ase-15.7

I have my sort ordering in Sybase as:
45  190 **altdict** -  Alternate (lower-case first) dictionary ordering
Am I right that alternate means "aAbBcC..zZ" ordering?

What should I do to change ordering with "ORDER BY" as 'ABC..YZabc..yz' ? What sort ordering to choose?

Where may it be changed? In a session? In SQL statement?
as far as I know I need to change the whole server sort ordering and rebuilt indexes. But there are a bunch of databases with different owners and different users and it seems a bit extreme

Comment: Which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) are you running?

Comment: @markp it's ASE 15.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASE dataserver is configured with a single sort order; see [selecting default sort order](https://help.sap.com/viewer/aa939a27edb34f019f71cc47b9c0fd9a/16.0.3.7/en-US/a7985e68bc2b1014a847e4919e0230fd.html).

For scenarios where the user needs to use a sort order different from the dataserver's default sort order there is:

- [sortkey()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2df920cd5b1644e5a065d55b637d5e92/16.0.3.7/en-US/aae2d757bc2b101495039132b7fd1c34.html) - allows for sorting data by a user-selected sort order

Comment: thank you, that totally answers my question

"select * from aksenov_test
order by
sortkey(a, 50) desc"

works perfect

Comment: good to hear; I don't recall having used `sortkey()` before so it's good to know something works as advertised in the documentation! :-)